# Will there be any string injections with the following code

Tags: perl

I have a page which displays name if present in the params, else displays the form to input a name.

```
my $name = $q->param('name');

print $q->header('text/html');
print '<!DOCTYPE html>';
print '<html lang="en">';
print '<head><title>Hello</title></head>';
print '<body>';

if (defined $name) {
    print "Hello ${name}!";
} else {
    print '<form method="post">';
    print 'Please enter your name:<br>';
    print '<input type="text" name="name"><br>';
    print '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
    print '</form>';
}
```

Comment: Job security for writing a new script in CGI? I kid! I kid!

Comment: Strip/Escape HTML from input param *name*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are [injecting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) arbitrary text (`$name`) into HTML without first converting it to HTML.

Replace

```
print "Hello ${name}!";
```

with

```
print escapeHTML("Hello ${name}!");
```

---

Whenever you concatenate strings (which you are implicitly doing through multiple uses of `print`), consider what you are concatenation together.

If you inject text into HTML, convert it to HTML text first.
If you inject text into SQL, convert it to a SQL literal first.
If you inject text into a shell command, convert it to a shell literal first.
...